# Go relationship error when migrating models using gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm, golang-migrate

I am new to go/golang and I have been learning it by trying to create a small project. I have written several models in my go project corresponding to the db tables I want in my db. I have opted to use PostgreSQL, when migrating the models I get the following error

```
ERROR: relation "personal_informations" does not exist (SQLSTATE 42P01)
[1.657ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE "employee_leaves_requests" 
("id" bigserial,"created_at" timestamptz,"updated_at" timestamptz,"deleted_at" timestamptz,
"emp_no" bigint NOT NULL,"reason" text NOT NULL,"leave_type_id" bigint NOT NULL,
"days_remaining" bigint NOT NULL,"leave_limit" text NOT NULL,"from_date" timestamptz NOT NULL,
"to_date" timestamptz NOT NULL,"leave_status" text NOT NULL,"status" text NOT NULL,"document_url" text NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_personal_informations_employee_leaves_request" FOREIGN KEY ("emp_no") 
REFERENCES "personal_informations"("id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_leave_types_employee_leaves_request" 
FOREIGN KEY ("leave_type_id") REFERENCES "leave_types"("id"))
```

These are the models that are not being migrated

```
type PersonalInformation struct {
    gorm.Model
    EmpNo         string `gorm:"not null"`
    Gender        string `gorm:"not null"`
    Surname       string `gorm:"not null"`
    FirstName     string `gorm:"not null"`
    MiddleName    string
    Dob           time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
    RoleID        uint      `gorm:"not null"`
    Town          string
    Country       string
    Location      string
    PhoneNumber   string `gorm:"not null"`
    MaritalStatus bool   `gorm:"not null"`
    ImageURL      string `gorm:"not null"`
    IsInsured     bool   `gorm:"not null"`
    Status        string

    Role                  Roles                    `gorm:"foreignKey:RoleID"`
    EmployeeLeavesRequest []EmployeeLeavesRequests `gorm:"foreignKey:EmpNo"`
    EmployeeLeave         []EmployeeLeaves         `gorm:"foreignKey:EmpNo"`
}

type EmployeeLeaves struct {
    gorm.Model
    EmpNo           string `gorm:"not null"`
    LeaveTypeId     uint   `gorm:"not null"`
    LeaveLimit      string `gorm:"not null"`
    AllocatedLeaves string `gorm:"not null"`
    Status          string `gorm:"not null"`

    PersonalInfo PersonalInformation `gorm:"foreignKey:EmpNo"`
    LeaveType    LeaveTypes          `gorm:"foreignKey:LeaveTypeId"`
}

type EmployeeLeavesRequests struct {
    gorm.Model
    EmpNo         string    `gorm:"not null"`
    Reason        string    `gorm:"not null"`
    LeaveTypeId   string    `gorm:"not null"`
    DaysRemaining int       `gorm:"not null"`
    LeaveLimit    string    `gorm:"not null"`
    FromDate      time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
    ToDate        time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
    LeaveStatus   string    `gorm:"not null"`
    Status        string    `gorm:"not null"`
    DocumentUrl   string    `gorm:"not null"`

    PersonalInfo PersonalInformation `gorm:"foreignKey:EmpNo"`
    LeaveType    LeaveTypes          `gorm:"foreignKey:LeaveTypeId"`
}
```

This is the method used to migrate

```
func MigrateModels() {
    dbName := "testdb"
    dbUser := "user"
    dbPassword := ""
    dbHost := "localhost"
    dbPort := "5432"

    connStr := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s host=%s port=%s sslmode=disable", dbUser, dbPassword, dbName, dbHost, dbPort)

    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DSN: connStr,
    }), &gorm.Config{})

    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    db.AutoMigrate(
        &Users{},
        &PersonalData{},
        &Roles{},
        &Teams{},
        &Departments{},
        &Holidays{},
        &PersonalInformation{},
        &LeaveTypes{},
        &EmployeeLeaves{},
        &EmployeeLeavesRequests{},
    )

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error migrating the models:", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println("Database migration completed successfully!")
}
```

Where could the error be coming from?

Answer (score 0):

It looks the issue happening here is due to the **circular dependancy** between the models.

`PersonalInformation` model has a relationship with `EmployeeLeavesRequest`  and `EmployeeLeave`. But again you defined a relationship in `EmployeeLeave` and `EmployeeLeavesRequest` to `PersonalInformation` as well.

```golang
type PersonalInformation struct {
    ...
    Role                  Roles                    `gorm:"foreignKey:RoleID"`
    EmployeeLeavesRequest []EmployeeLeavesRequests `gorm:"foreignKey:EmpNo"`
    EmployeeLeave         []EmployeeLeaves         `gorm:"foreignKey:EmpNo"`
}

type EmployeeLeaves struct {
    ...
    PersonalInfo PersonalInformation `gorm:"foreignKey:EmpNo"`
}

type EmployeeLeavesRequests struct {
    ...
    PersonalInfo PersonalInformation `gorm:"foreignKey:EmpNo"`
}
```

As a result, the dependency becomes `circular`.

**The order of GORM Migration**

- In the absence of dependencies between models, GORM will migrate them in the order that they are defined in code.
- As long as there are dependencies between models, it will generate tables in the correct order to comply with foreign key constraints.

Therefore, the GORM tries to create `employee_leaves` before creating `personal_informations`, and it fails.

**Solution**

Make sure your model structs are defined in an order that respects their dependencies for the correct migration order.

You can remove the dependency with `PersonalInformation` from `EmployeeLeaves` and  `EmployeeLeavesRequests`.

Enable `logging` to see the logs, and `DryRun` to generate SQL without running it, so that you can see the migration SQL order.

```golang
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DSN: connStr,
    }), &gorm.Config{
        Logger: logger.Default.LogMode(logger.Info), // Enable logging mode
        DryRun: true, // DryRun generate sql without execute
    })
```